# In app purchase is not working now but it work in past in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

In app purchase is not working now but it work in past in objective c. 
It works perfectly in past but now it does not show any details of the product name price. Please some one give some solution.

Here i sending my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSLog(@"%@",entityid);
[super viewDidLoad];
purchasedItemIDs=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    [self restrictRotation:YES];
}
else{
    [self restrictRotation:YES];
}
[self translation];

activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(157*scalex, 170*scaley, 20, 20)];
[activityIndicatorView setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[activityIndicatorView setColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
CGAffineTransform transform;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.85f, .85f);
}
else
{
      transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
}
activityIndicatorView.transform = transform;
[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

_v2.hidden=YES;
_price.hidden=YES;
_productPriceLabel.hidden=YES;
_productTitleLabel.hidden=YES;
_productDescriptionLabel.hidden=YES;
_purchaseButton.hidden = YES;
_viewdetails.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
[self fetchAvailableProducts];
}

 -(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
 NSLog(@"%@",entityid);
 if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
 {
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                  initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                  [NSSet setWithObject:entityid]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
 }
 else{
    _productDescriptionLabel.text =
    @"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings";
 }


}
-(void)translation{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;


    if( screenHeight == 568&&screenWidth==320  ){
        scaley=1.183;
        scalex=1.0;
    } else if ( screenWidth==375&&screenHeight==667 ){

        scalex=1.171;
        scaley=1.39;

    } else if (screenWidth==540&&screenHeight==960 ){
        scaley=2.0;
        scalex=1.168;

    } else {
        scalex=1.0;
        scaley=1.0;

    }


}
else{
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    if(screenWidth>screenHeight){
        scaley=1.6;
        scalex=3.2;

    }
    else if(screenWidth<screenHeight){
        scalex=2.4;
        scaley=2.133;
    }


}


}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{


NSLog(@"%@",response);


NSArray *products = response.products;

NSLog(@"%@",products);

if (products.count != 0)
{

    NSLog(@"%@",products);
    product = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLocale *priceLocale = product.priceLocale;
    NSDecimalNumber *price = product.price;
    NSString *description = product.localizedDescription;
    //validProducts = [products objectAtIndex:0];
    _purchaseButton.enabled = YES;
    _productTitleLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
    [_productTitleLabel sizeToFit];
    _productDescriptionLabel.text = description;


     CGFloat rr=[self heightForText:description];
    _productDescriptionLabel.frame=CGRectMake(_productDescriptionLabel.frame.origin.x,_productDescriptionLabel.frame.origin.y, _productDescriptionLabel.frame.size.width, rr);

    _v2.frame=CGRectMake(_v2.frame.origin.x,_productDescriptionLabel.frame.origin.y+rr+10, _v2.frame.size.width, _v2.frame.size.height);

    _price.frame=CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x,_v2.frame.origin.y+5, _v2.frame.size.width, _price.frame.size.height);

    _productPriceLabel.frame=CGRectMake(_productPriceLabel.frame.origin.x,_v2.frame.origin.y+5, _productPriceLabel.frame.size.width, _productPriceLabel.frame.size.height);
    _productDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines=rr/10.0;
    NSString *rupree=[priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
    rupree1=[priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    NSString *ui=[rupree stringByAppendingString:[price stringValue]];
    _productPriceLabel.text=ui;
    rup=[price stringValue];
    _v2.hidden=NO;
    _price.hidden=NO;
    _productPriceLabel.hidden=NO;
    _productTitleLabel.hidden=NO;
    _productDescriptionLabel.hidden=NO;
} else {
     _productTitleLabel.text = @"Product not found";
}}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
 {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:{

            NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[receiptUrl path]])
            {
              //  NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
                //NSString *receiptStr = [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
                //NSLog(@"%@",receiptStr);
            }

           // if (hasAddObserver==YES) {
           if(![purchasedItemIDs containsObject:idf]){
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
            // NSString *email=[_email text];
            NSString *escapedString = [email stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@",escapedString];
           idf=entityid;

            NSString *post5=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&price=%@",rup];
            NSString *post6=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&pricecode=%@",rupree1];
            NSString *post4;
            if ([idf isEqualToString:@"com.onlinebusinessschool.com.OnlineBusinessSchool.pricenew30"]||[idf isEqualToString:@"com.onlinebusinessschool.com.OnlineBusinessSchool.pricenew76"]||[idf isEqualToString:@"com.onlinebusinessschool.com.OnlineBusinessSchool.pricenew34"]){
                 post4=[idf stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"com.onlinebusinessschool.com.OnlineBusinessSchool.pricenew" withString:@""];

            }
             else{
                 post4=[idf stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"com.onlinebusinessschool.com.OnlineBusinessSchool.price" withString:@""];
            }
            NSString *post1=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&id=%@",post4];
            NSString *post3=[post stringByAppendingString:post1];
            NSString *post51=[post5 stringByAppendingString:post6];
                NSLog(@"%@",post4);
            NSString *post511=[post3 stringByAppendingString:post51];
            NSString *url1=@"http://learn.onlinebusinessschool.com/learn-app/order-assessment.php?";
            NSString *hostStr = [url1 stringByAppendingString:post511];
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr];
            NSLog(@"%@",url);
            NSData *postData = [post511 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSData *responseData1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:urlData];
                NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                NSLog(@"new=%@",jsonObject);
                orderid1=[jsonObject objectForKey:@"invoiceId"];
                purchasedetails *mvc;

                if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

                    mvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad_storyboard" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"purchasedetails"];
                }
                else{
                    mvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"purchasedetails"];
                }
                mvc.name=name;
                mvc.email=email;
                mvc.customer_id=customer_id;
                mvc.password=password;
                mvc.entitytype=idf;


                mvc.label21=label3;
                mvc.coursetype=label1;
                mvc.orderid1=orderid1;
                mvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];

            }
            }
            for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
            {
                NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
                [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
                NSLog(@"%@",purchasedItemIDs);
            }
            [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

            [self unlockFeature];


        }
        //}
            break;
         case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
             [self displayAlertViewWithMessage:@"Wait! transaction is failed ....."];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
             finishTransaction:transaction];
            [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored: {


            break;
        }
         case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: {
             //[//[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            // currently purchasing
           // [self displayAlertViewWithMessage:@"Wait! Purchasing ....."];

             activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(157*scalex, 150*scaley, 20, 20)];
             [activityIndicatorView setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
             [activityIndicatorView setColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
             [self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
             CGAffineTransform transform;
             if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                 transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.75f, .75f);
             }
             else{
                 transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
             }
             activityIndicatorView.transform = transform;
             [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to describe your problem better and provide some code sample, so we can figure out, what we are dealing with...

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. It's well described in [ask] article in [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Fix your code.

Seriously, this could be anything from your server misbehaving, to the in-app purchase being registered incorrectly at Apple, to your code only working by coincidence in the first place.

Just start debugging your code. Or go back to previous versions in your source code control, see if it is working there, and check what is the first version that fails and what you changed in that version.

Comment: But it works perfectly in past. I my self purchase 2 products. But now product details, price, etc does comes though the product ID correct.

Comment: Yes The problem in product key.